# Auto Closing Windows Credential Prompt for Outlook2016

Tags: vbscript, outlook, autohotkey

Trying to use AutoHotkey to close this prompt as it comes up,
i'm closing the window based on Titles, that mean any other windows credential request will get auto closed also, is there any way that i can identify that this popup prompt is generated by Outlook2016 and only then the script can close the window?

OS: Windows 10

Script:

```
#NoEnv 
#Persistent
SetTimer, ClosePopup, 250
return

ClosePopup:
WinClose, Windows Security
return
```

i also tried VBS, but 2 issue, i also cant make sure this prompt is from outlook and the second is that the script wont loop

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 

Do 
    ret = wshShell.AppActivate("Windows Security") 
    If ret = True Then 
        wshShell.SendKeys "%{F4}" 'ALT F4 
        Exit Do 
    End If 
    WScript.Sleep 500 
Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
WinClose Windows Security ahk_exe outlook.exe
```